# Why Electric field inside the spherical shell is zero?

Tags: electrostatics, electrons, electric-fields, gauss-law, conductors

[electric field in and out of the spherical shell](https://youtu.be/aPARoNOIrek)

Why the field inside the conducting spherical shell is zero? 
Professor Lewin said and I quote,"  there is NO charge inside the conductor 
because any charge inside the conductor would make the electrons experience a force , the electrons will start to flow and they will kill the electric field."  But he says Electric field is zero inside the conductor and for that charge should be present to provide the electrons with force to cancel the field . Isn't it ?

Comment: By Gauss's law, as net charge in the spherical shell is zero so flux is zero which concludes that electric field inside the spherical shell is zero.

Comment: It is an essential to mention that the shel is a **conductor**. Otherwise the electric field may be non zero.

Comment: @Shreyansh Going by what Prof Lewin said there should be charge present . But he said NO charge (either positive or negative or both).

Comment: @BeyondZero I do not understand what your question really asks for. Could you rephrase it?

Comment: @Beyond Zero according to whatever I studied I think that net charge enclosed in the spherical shell must be zero but the charges are present on the outer surface of the shell.

Comment: It is not a duplicate because one can study field due to spherical shell before studying conductors!

Comment: @KV18 In lecture , prof said charge should be present that can apply force on the electrons and that can kill the electric field. That is why field is zero in the conducting spherical shell. Just watch a few minor of the video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is "why is the static electric field inside a conductor always zero?". The video is not really needed. Any nonzero field in a conductor can only be transient as it would create a current until the charge has redistributed in such a way that the field is zero.

Nevertheless, I watched the part of the video that describes a spherical conducting shell with total charge -3Q with a charge of +Q at the center. There is a field corresponding to +Q in the void inside the shell and one corresponding to -2Q outside the conductor. So far so good.

The field is nulled inside the conductor by an induced charge distribution. This distribution amounts to -Q on the inner surface and +Q on the outer surface.

Here we see an *error* in the video. The real charge distribution on the shell is the sum of the induced distribution and the original one, that is -Q on the inner and -2Q on the outer surface of the conducting shell.

The risk of online physics courses is that the, even MIT, material may not be properly reviewed for inaccuracies like these.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply Gauss' law inside the sphere. Consider any arbitrary Gaussian surface inside the sphere. The charge enclosed by that surface is zero. From Gauss' law 
$$ \oint{ \bf{E.dA}} =0$$
This implies that the electric field inside a sphere is zero.

Say you now add an electron inside the shell. The electrons on the surface will experience a force. This will cause them to move on the surface such that the net force\field becomes zero again.